# With Lucene, determine which name in a SQL Table exists in a document

Tags: lucene

I have a SQL table with people’s names and I want to find out which name is in a document that I’ve indexed with Lucene.
Is there a way find out other than searching for each name individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you can achieve that by using     `WildcardQuery` and searching only for **"*"** string.

```
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(new WildcardQuery(new Term(AppConstants.NAME, "*")), 20);

            if (null == hits.scoreDocs || hits.scoreDocs.length <= 0) {
                System.out.println("No Hits Found");
                return;
            }

    for (ScoreDoc hit : hits.scoreDocs) {
        Document doc = searcher.doc(hit.doc);
        .......build a list of names or whatever or cross check with DB table etc etc......
    }
```

In above code, `AppConstants.NAME` is name field name and its assumed that reader and `searcher` have already been initialized.

In place of hit limit of `20` , you can specify any number that you want depending on number of rows in table.

Be prepared that search with wild card will be slow and depends heavily on your index size.

When asking question on Lucene, always specify Lucene version and API technology - Java or .NET.

Above Java code works for me with Lucene 6.0.0.